# making algorithm for getting programmer efficiency

Tags: algorithm

I have some data about programmer actions inside an ide. From this data I am trying to make a good algorithm to calculate a programmers efficiency.

If we consider

> efficiency = useful energy out / energy in

I made this rough equation:

> energy in = active time(run events x code editing time)

Basically its the the time where stuff is actually being done by the programmer multiplied by run events like 
debugging,build etc x the time where the programmer is actually editing code.

> useful energy out = energy in - (#unsuccessfulbuilds + abortedtestruns
>   + debuggerusetime)

Useful energy out is basically energy in minus things that I consider to be inefficient.

Can anyone see how to improve this, particularly from a mathematical point of view. Maths isn't my strong point and am not sure if I should use some sort of weighting for the equations and how to do this correctly. Also, I'm thinking of how to make it that whats minused from energy in in the useful energy out equation cant end up as less than 0. Can anyone give a hand with these questions ?

Comment: Have you tried running some experiments, using your current algorithm, and seeing how useful the result is? If the results of your algorithm seem arbitrary then adjust it. It certainly seems like the term *useful energy out* is essentially subjective in this instance, so I'd just try it first if I was you.

Comment: I havent coded it yet but plan to in the next week and test it. Just wanted to get some opinions on it first before hand to not waste time on something I didnt realize

Comment: In that case, you should know that Stack Overflow generally expects you to have completed some of your work first, so that they can give you constructive criticism in order to refine your code and solve your problem. Asking others to spend their time in order to prevent "wasting" yours is, in my opinion, frankly rude and not in the spirit of this website's generous way of operating

Comment: Thats understandable, my thought process was if someone that has more experience can see an obvious issue in a minute it can save me possibly hours. I feel that constructive criticism could be given on what I have done up until now and wasn't expecting someone to implement and test what I have done but could possibly notice an obvious mistake.

Comment: If you expect savings in terms of hours, from asking about this topic on Stack Overflow you might be in over your head. Software engineering researchers have spent days, months and years, doing actual research for coming up with useful software engineering measurements - not being altogether successful yet. On that note, a question like this could be considered off-topic for Stack Overflow, since it's not really a programming question. It would probably be much more fitting for [softwareengineering.stackexchange.com](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com).

Answer (score 2):

Your "algorithm" is completely arbitrary, making judgement of value over things that are inocuous to whatever you called "efficient/inneficient", and will endup with a completely incoherent final value after being calculated. Compilation time? So the first compilation of a C++ plugin that takes 30+ minutes is good? Debugging time is both efficient and inefficient in your proposal.
A programmer that codes for 10 minutes and make 6 consecutive builds with close to no changes will have the same output as the guy that code for 60 minutes.
I suggest you look firts to what is a good use of a programmers time, how other programs contabilize programmers efficiency. Etc.
Just on a side note, to create a model of efficiency of work of a highly technical and creative field, you must understand quite well math, statistics and project management. Thats why good scrum masters are so sought after.
Anyway, what you propose is not an algorithm, but a scoring system, usually algorithms do make use of scoring systems to help their internal rules work out the best solution based on the scoring. The scoring is just a value, while the algorithm is a process to an end.